# Problem in understanding the proof of boundedness of a convergent sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

I was seeing [Prove: Convergent sequences are bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213936/prove-convergent-sequences-are-bounded). The proof is as follows:

> Let $s_n$ be a convergent sequence, and let $\lim s_n = s$. Then taking $\epsilon = 1$ we have:
>
> $n > N \implies |s_n - s| < 1$
>
> From the triangle inequality we see that: $ n > N \implies|s_n| - |s| < 1 \iff |s_n| < |s| + 1$.
>
> Define $M= \max\{|s|+1, |s_1|, |s_2|, ..., |s_N|\}$. Then we have $|s_n| \leq M$ for all $n \in N$.

I've some problem in understanding the approach of this deduction.

We need to show that the sequence is bounded which means $|s_n| \le M$ . Now, this must be for every $n$. What I am not understanding is whether the first step to show that for $n \gt N$, $|s_n| \lt |s| +1$ was necessary. After all, a number $M$ greater than all the sequence-elements were taken next; so why not, take this step firstly?

I only want to know how the first step for showing that for $n \gt N$, $|s_n| \lt |s| +1$ is essential for the proof. Also, it deduced that $|s_n| \color{red}{\lt} |s| +1$; so how did, finally, at the last step of proof $\color{\red}\le$ come in place of $\color{red}{\lt}$? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M$ was *not* chosen to be greater than all terms of the sequence: it was chosen to be at least as large as $|s|+1$ and the first $N$ terms of the sequence.

The first step takes care of all but the first $N$ terms: there is some integer $N$ such that $|s_n|<|s|+1$ whenever $n>N$. Thus, $|s|+1$ is almost an upper bound for the sequence: it’s bigger than the absolute value of every term except possibly one or more of the terms $s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_N$, However, there are only finitely many of those terms, so we can pick the one with largest absolute value; say that it’s $s_m$. Now we know that $|s_k|\le |s_m|$ if $1\le k\le N$, and $|s_k|<|s|+1$ if $k>N$. If we now let $M=\max\{|s|+1,|s_m|\}$, we know that

$$|s_k|\le|s_M|\le M$$

if $1\le k\le N$, and

$$|s_k|<|s|+1\le M$$

if $k>N$, so $|s_k|\le M$ for all $k$. Thus, the sequence lies entirely in the interval $[-M,M]$ and is therefore bounded.

As for your last question, if $a<b$, then it’s certainly also true that $a\le b$: if you know the former inequality, you can certainly claim the latter.

The basic idea of the proof is that since the sequence is convergent, it must eventually get *and stay* close to its limit $s$. In this specific argument we choose $N$ so that $|s_n-s|<1$ whenever $n>N$, so that the sequence stays within one unit of $s$. The first $N$ terms could be anywhere, but *there are only finitely many of them*, so there is a largest (in absolute value). Thus, we have the bound $|s|+1$ that is known to work for all but the first $N$ terms, and we can get a bound on that finite set of terms. We then take the larger of these bounds and can be confident that it bounds every term.

Comment: Sir, thanks for the answer. Shouldn't in $s_k\le|s_M|\le M$ & $s_k<|s|+1\le M$, there would be $|\;\;|$ in $s_k$; in the above lines you've written them correctly including $|\;\;|$ sign: "Now we know that $|s_k|≤|s_m|$ if $1≤k≤N$, and $|s_k|<|s|+1$ if $k \gt N$"; but later, you didn't mention them. So, I think this is a typo:|

Comment: Also, I want to know how you inferred $|s_k|\le M$ from $|s_k|<|s|+1\le M$;  Yes it is accurate to write that $|s_k| \lt M$ but why the equality? $|s|+1$ can be equal to $M$ but not $|s_k|$ since it is less than $|s|+1$. So, can you help me shun this confusion?

Comment: @user36790: Yes, I inadvertently omitted the absolute value signs around $s_k$ in the displayed formulas; they’re fixed now. Thanks for noticing. \\ From $|s_k|<|s|+1\le M$ we can, as you say, actually infer that $|s_k|<M$, but of course if this is true, then it’s certainly also true that $|s_k|\le M$. For $1\le k\le N$, however, we can infer only that $|s_k|\le M$. Thus, the best that we can claim for *all* $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ is that $|s_k|\le M$. If we defined $$M=\max\{|s|+1,|s_1|+1,\ldots,|s_N|+1\}\;,$$ then we could infer that $|s_k|<M$ for all $k$, since for $1\le k\le N$ we would have ...

Comment: ... $|s_k|<|s_k|+1\le M$. But we don’t need this: in order to show that that sequence is bounded, we need only show that there is an $M$ such that $|s_k|\le M$ for all $k$, and we’ve done that. (It may help to point out that it’s perfectly correct to write, for instance, $2\le 3$, even though we know that in fact the stronger statement $2<3$ is true.)

Answer (score 0):

The point is that the definition of convergence only says that given any positive error margin **eventually** the elements in the sequence will be within that error margin around the limit. We do not know **when** that eventual situation would be, so we have no choice but to separately bound the initial part of the sequence before that point. Thankfully that initial part has **finitely** many numbers and hence is bounded, so since the latter part is also bounded, the whole thing is bounded.

Also, if $a < b$ then $a \le b$ so there is nothing wrong with doing that last step.

Answer (score 0):

According to definition of convergent sequence after certain stage all terms of sequence lies in a band. I.e $L-\epsilon<a_n<L +\epsilon$ after n greater than equal to m say. This means after m, the sequence is bounded above by $L+\epsilon$. So we need to worry about terms from $n=1$ to $n=m-1$. Let we have P be the maximum value of these terms and let us take $M=\max\{P,L+\epsilon\}$. So sequence is bounded above by $M$.

Comment: This is a very common proof technique.