# What's an example of a convergent, yet unbounded sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What's an example of a convergent, yet unbounded sequence?

I'm having trouble of thinking how to do this. I want to use a piecewise function, but I feel like there might be something easier than this.

Comment: A convergent sequence is always bounded. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213936/prove-convergent-sequences-are-bounded

Comment: Are you talking about a sequence consisting of numbers or a sequence consisting of functions?

Answer (score 1):

Rise is correct. I can't believe I didn't see this sooner. all convergent sequences are bounded. I was confusing this with convergent functions, which are different. (i.e. $f(x)= \frac {1}{x}$)

Answer (score -1):

Consider the sequence of functions on the interval $(0,1)$ given by $f_n(x) = nx^n$. Note that $f_n(x)$ converges to $0$ point wise on $(0,1)$. However, $f_n(x)$ is unbounded on $(0,1)$.

Comment: So I prove this then using two subsequences? Doesn't what you gave not work since $n$ implies integers?

Comment: A sequence is indexed by the natural numbers.