# Proof verification about Abel's test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I've seen several proofs of Abel's test, but still I'm not sure if the proofs are as precious as they can be, hence I decided to proof the test and add some details whenever it's needed:

Theorem: Assume $\left\{a_{k}\right\}_{k\ge1},\left\{b_{k}\right\}_{k\ge1}$ are two real sequences, if  $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}$ is convergent , $\left\{b_{k}\right\}_{k\ge1}$ is monotonic and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b_{k}$ is convergent, then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}b_{k}$ is also a convergent series.

Proof:

First define $$S_{n}:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}\;\;\;\;,\;\;\text{and notice that}  \;\;\;\;,\;\;S_0=0$$

and consider the following finite series:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}b_{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(S_{k}-S_{k-1}\right)b_{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}S_{k}b_{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}S_{k-1}b_{k}$$

Setting $k-1 \mapsto k$ in the right series follows:

$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n}S_{k}b_{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}S_{k}b_{k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}S_{k}\left(b_{k}-b_{k+1}\right)+S_{n}b_{n+1}$$

Hence we showed that:

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}b_{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}S_{k}\left(b_{k}-b_{k+1}\right)+S_{n}b_{n+1}}$$

---

Since $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}$ is convergent we conclude that $\lim_{n \to \infty}S_n$ does exist and is a finite value, from [convergent sequences are bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213936/prove-convergent-sequences-are-bounded) it follows that there exist a real number $M$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb N^{+}$: $\left|S_{n}\right|\le M$, now it's the time to use this fact:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|S_{k}\left(b_{k}-b_{k+1}\right)\right|=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|S_{k}\right|\left|\left(b_{k}-b_{k+1}\right)\right|\le\sum_{k=1}^{n}M\left|\left(b_{k}-b_{k+1}\right)\right|=M\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|\left(b_{k}-b_{k+1}\right)\right|$$

If $\left\{b_{k}\right\}_{k\ge1}$ is monotone decreasing then we have:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|\left(b_{k}-b_{k+1}\right)\right|=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(b_{k}-b_{k+1}\right)=b_{1}-b_{n+1}$$

Taking the limit of this expression:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|\left(b_{k}-b_{k+1}\right)\right|=\lim_{n \to \infty}b_{1}-\lim_{n \to \infty}b_{n+1}$$

From [term test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test) we conclude:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|\left(b_{k}-b_{k+1}\right)\right|=b_1$$

If $\left\{b_{k}\right\}_{k\ge1}$ is monotone increasing then we have:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|\left(b_{k}-b_{k+1}\right)\right|=-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(b_{k}-b_{k+1}\right)=-b_{1}+b_{n+1}$$

Again using the previous result yields:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|\left(b_{k}-b_{k+1}\right)\right|=-b_1$$

In either cases it's seen that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|\left(b_{k}-b_{k+1}\right)\right|$ is convergent, from Constant Multiple Rule of convergent series we see that $M\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|\left(b_{k}-b_{k+1}\right)\right|$ converges and using [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) tells us that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|S_{k}\left(b_{k}-b_{k+1}\right)\right|$ is also convergent, on the other hand we know that [Absolutely Convergent Series is Convergent](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Absolutely_Convergent_Series_is_Convergent), so $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}S_{k}\left(b_{k}-b_{k+1}\right)$ is convergent, besides $S_{n}b_{n+1}$ is fixed value, concludes:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}b_{k} \;\;\;\;\;\;\text{converges}$$

Q.E.D.

---

I'm not sure if I've used the theorems properly, so can someone verify my proof?

**Note**

There is a little difference between this theorem and the theorem used in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test), because Wikipedia claims that the sequence $\left\{b_{k}\right\}_{k\ge1}$ must be bounded, but I replaced this condition to "$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b_{k}$ is convergent",  if we just consider the Wiki's condition, then the proof won't change that much, I will show that my theorem implies Wiki's theorem but the converse is not true:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b_{k}$ is convergent then nth term test implies $$\lim_{k \to \infty}b_{k}=0 \iff \forall \epsilon >0, \exists N \in \mathbb N^{+}:\forall k\left(k\ge N \implies \left|b_{k}\right|<\epsilon\right)$$
So it's shown that the sequence $\left\{b_{k}\right\}_{k\ge N}$ is bounded.

Now I'm going to show that the converse is not true, a classic example is Harmonic series, because $\forall k \in \mathbb N^{+}$:

$$\frac{1}{k}\le1$$

However the sequence $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$ is not convergent.

Comment: I believe you missed the term for $k = 0$ in the equation in the green box.

Comment: @vonbrand, I have not, since $S_0=0$ then it's equals to zero and I prevented of mentioning that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is sound (well done!) except for one detail at the end, where you say "besides $S_nb_{n+1}$ is fixed value". Since $S_nb_{n+1}$ depends on $n$, it does affect what happens when $n\to\infty$ in your green box. Fortunately the sequence $(S_n)$ is bounded, and by your hypothesis $b_n\to0$, so
$\lim S_nb_{n+1}=0$,
and you can properly conclude that $\sum a_kb_k$ converges.

**Note** that your theorem has the condition that $\sum b_k$ converges. This makes your theorem **less** general than the Wiki version. It is true that "$\sum b_k$ converges" implies "$(b_k)$ bounded", but this means that your condition is *harder* to satisfy, so your theorem    is not usable in as many situations as the Wiki version. For example, you cannot apply your theorem to the case where $b_k$ is identically $1$ to conclude the obvious fact that $\sum a_k \cdot 1$ converges.

Comment: You are totally true, but let me ask you some questions to make sure that I got your point, you proved $\lim S_nb_{n+1}=0$ because $S_n$ is bounded and since $\sum b_k$ converges using nth term test implies that $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n=0$, and you (I guess ) have used squeeze theorem, now assume we are working on Wiki's theorem, I'm not sure how to prove $\lim S_nb_{n+1}=0$, but at least I know their limit is a finite value , since both $S_n$ and $b_n$ are bounded, can you help me to prove $\lim S_nb_{n+1}=0$ based on Wiki'ss theorem?

Comment: I think even without proving $\lim S_nb_{n+1}=0$ we still are able to prove that $\sum a_kb_k$ converges (in Wiki's theorem) , because it equals to $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}S_{k}\left(b_{k}-b_{k+1}\right)+S_{n}b_{n+1}$$  I already showed that the series on the left is convergent and also in the previous comment I showed that $S_{n}b_{n+1}$ always has a finite value, so a convergent series plus a finite value is convergent again and hence $\sum a_kb_k$ converges.

Comment: @user715522 To your second point: To prove that $\sum a_kb_k$ converges you need to show that $S_nb_{n+1}$ converges. It is not enough to show that $S_nb_{n+1}$ has a finite value for each $n$. For example the quantity $(-1)^n$ always has a finite value but it does not converge.

Comment: @user715522 To your first point: The Wiki proof will show that $S_nb_{n+1}$ converges, and that is all we need. In the Wiki version the limit is not necessarily zero, but in your version the limit is known to be zero.

Comment: Thanks, I got it, can you just show that how in Wiki version we can show that $S_nb_{n+1}$ converges?

Comment: @user715522 In the Wiki version $S_n$ is convergent (same as in your proof) and $b_n$ is convergent (because it is monotone and bounded). Finally the product of two convergent sequences is convergent.